# removing parent classes in Backbone Marionette CompositeViews

Tags: jquery, marionette

Hi I'm trying to do a simple stuff(please take into consideration that I'm new in Marionette + CSS + jquery).
What I'm trying to do is:
I have to 2 divs that when the page is loaded, they have some specific class style(inactive style red color), when the user clicks on one of them I remove the 'inactive' class and insert the 'active' class style, green color.
I'm using Marionnette CompositeView to render my elements, the problem is that the 'inactive' class is removed but the active class is not added, I simplify my problem in:

```
<script id="ulTemplate" type="text/template">
    <ul class="ulItem">
    </ul>
</script>
<script id="internal-Item" type="text/template">    
    <div class="<%= className %>"></div>
</script>    
<div class="container">
</div>
```

[My JS/CSS/Code](http://jsfiddle.net/xbBEy/37/)
The reason I'm setting background to the parent elements (the extra div CompositeView is adding) is because the final result my div should have an image.
This is a very simplify example, in the end it will become a more complex element, but for now I'm stuck with the first step(I think the easier step).
Please help me here, I have mercy with your comments, again new in the areas.

Answer (score 0):

Actually your code is working and the class is being changed but the issue is that you are changing the class from "internal-Item-inactive" to "switcher-item-background-active" in your
addClasstoParentElement function. and that class is not the one you are passing as parameter, also is not defined in your css.

making this change in that function made the trick.

```
       addClasstoParentElement: function (options) {
           if (!options.element.parent().hasClass(options.className)) {
                options.element.parent().addClass(options.className); // "internal-Item-active"
           }
```

please check this link
http://jsfiddle.net/xbBEy/64/

I added the code and the explanation on it.

```
        this.removeClassfromParentElement({element:this.ui.div1, className: "internal-Item-inactive"});
            this.addClasstoParentElement({element: this.ui.div1, className: "internal-Item-active"}); 
            // and here we make the second div Inactive, 
            // this referst to this specific Itemview that indeed contains div1 but does not contains div2 so you cannot use   
           // this.ui.div2 as it will be undefined. thats why is find it using    $('.did2') its  that is traversing the entire dom to find it.
    this.removeClassfromParentElement({element:$('.div2').closest('div'), className: "internal-Item-active"});
            this.addClasstoParentElement({element: $('.div2').closest('div'), className: "internal-Item-inactive"});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you were right my mistake, I changed the code(you can see in the link I posted), but still when trying to remove the class from the other div that became 'active' the class is not remove and get in the end with two divs with the same class(both active -green color), thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks this is what I was missing, thanks a lot, now after looking into the code, I have a question, is this the right way?, maybe I need another object that will manage the changes(in my case the CompositeView, maybe the object ItemView object doesn't have to do this, what do you think.

Comment: I completely agree with you this is not the right way, I think you need to fire an event in your itemView, the CompositeView should handle this event, I dont have the background of your project so I can't give you an better advice than handle this changes using events with the eventAgregator component of marionette.